Angular is not loading the data from Oracle into the HTML
I'm trying to populate a table with data from an Oracle database locally. The database loads correctly in TypeScript, and it provides the data, but it doesn't display in the HTML.
Code:
app.component.ts

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { runQuery } from './database';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

export interface Product {
  ID: number;
  NAME: string;
  DESCRIPTION: string;
  PRICE: number;
  CATEGORY: string;
}

@Component({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  standalone: true 
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'proyecto';
  data: Product[] = [];
  loading: boolean = true;


    ngOnInit() {
      this.loadData();
    }
    constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  
    async loadData() {
      try {
        const result = await runQuery();
        if (result !== undefined) {
          console.log(result);
          this.data = result;
          this.loading = false;
        } else {
          console.error('Error');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error( error);
      }
    }
  }
  

app.component.html
<h1>Database Oracle</h1>

<table >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
      <th>PRICE</th>
      <th>CATEGORY</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let product of data">
      <td>{{ product.ID }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.NAME }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.DESCRIPTION }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.PRICE }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.CATEGORY }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




// database.ts
import { connectToDatabase } from './conexion';
import { Product } from './app.component'; 

export async function runQuery(): Promise<Product[]> {
  let connection;

  try {
    connection = await connectToDatabase();

    const result = await connection.execute(
      `SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS`
    );

    console.log(result.rows);
    return result.rows as Product[];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al ejecutar la consulta:', error);
    throw error;
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al cerrar la conexión:', error);
      }
    }
  }
}



// conexion.ts

import oracledb from 'oracledb';

const dbConfig: oracledb.ConnectionAttributes = {
  user: 'SYSTEM',
  password: 'ToorDam2',
  connectString: 'localhost:1521/XE' 
};

export async function connectToDatabase() {

  try {
    const connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);
    console.log('Connected');
    return connection;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error :', error);
    throw error;
  }
}


Issue: Data from the Oracle database is not being loaded/displayed in the HTML
the data loads in the AppComponent, it doesn't appear in the HTML. Could it be that the HTML is rendered before the AppComponent? What could be a solution?
I have no errors
just this:
browser-external:util:9 Module "util" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "util.inspect" in client code
but i dont think is that
thankkk

can you also share loadData ?

How did you find The database loads correctly in TypeScript,? Can you share the result of console.log(result);

Hey i dont have enough reputation to comment to ask for additional questions, so i have to write it as an answer, ill update this once you answer.
Which version of angular are you using?
This is relevant because it looks like you are not creating any Observables or Signals to emit that data was updated from [] to [data from oracle]. Angular relies heavily on the Behavior Subject Pattern.
what is happening is that you are initializing data with an empty array [] so the html template uses this initial value to render. you are loading the data after the component renders which is why its not updating. if you want to update this will not automatically, you will need to emit a change has occurred. by creating either an observable or a signal to accomplish this.
if you are using Angular 17+, then you can use Signals to update the variables like this:
import the signal from angular core
import { signal } from '@angular/core';

then update the values like this:
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'proyecto';
  data: Product[] = signal([]);
  loading: boolean = signal(true);


    ngOnInit() {
      this.loadData();
    }
    constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  
    async loadData() {
      try {
        const result = await runQuery();
        if (result !== undefined) {
          console.log(result);
          this.data.set(result);
          this.loading.set(false);
        } else {
          console.error('Error');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error( error);
      }
    }
  }


and on your html template you would just envoke the signal to get its current value and it will update automatically whenever loading or data changes.
<h1>Database Oracle</h1>

<table >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
      <th>PRICE</th>
      <th>CATEGORY</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let product of data()">
      <td>{{ product.ID }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.NAME }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.DESCRIPTION }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.PRICE }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.CATEGORY }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



if you are using Angular 17 or below, this wont work since you wont have access to signals. let me know and i will update the answer to use Observables which is the older way of doing things.
you can learn more about angular signals here: https://angular.io/guide/signals
